# How to align text in a table cell?

Tags: css, html-table, alignment

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="41" value="1">   
         Don't overwhelm yourself
         <span style="color:black;float:right">111111</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The text `111111` doesn't go to the right.

When I use `align:right`, it is the same.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="41" value="1">   
         Don't overwhelm yourself
         <span style="color:black;align:right">111111</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- width 100%, so we can see the floating -->
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <!-- width 100%, so we can see the floating -->
    <td style="width:100%" >

      <!-- float to left -->
      <input style="float:left" type="checkbox" id="41" value="1">    
      <span style="float:left"> Don't overwhelm yourself </span> 

      <!-- float to right -->
      <span style="color:black;float:right">111111</span> 

      <!-- clear floating -->
      <br style="clear:both" /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

check sample [here](http://jsbin.com/oyaka)

Answer (score 1):

The `span` tag is not a block one (css: `display=block;`), it is inline. It means that it does not occupy the whole line, and text inside it is not aligned (visually).

Replace your `span` with `div`, it will work.

To have different alignments on the same line, you need a bit of CSS tricks:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="41" value="1"> Don't overwhelm yourself</label>
    </div>
<div style="float: right;">
    111111
    </div>
```

Comment: What brower? I guess you're using IE6 :) That code is valid and the best way to have two different alignments at one line. It should work at least in "good" browsers.

Comment: Plus one for explaining the concept, i.e.: the difference between spans and divs, which is crucial for understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Span can't change page flow, so you can't use floats with span.

Comment: Wrong. Floating a span makes it a block-level element. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create the problem. Assuming you don't have any reason not to use simply 2 table cells.

Also, align never works. You should use text-align.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="41" value="1">Don't overwhelm yourself
    </td>
    <td style="color:black;text-align:right">
      111111
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```